# how can we add a "package" using composer where it is available on github, I do found one work, but this one doesn't

Tags: php, reference, composer-php

we can add a github repo as below then run `composer install`

```
  "config": {
            "allow-plugins": {
                    "composer/installers": true
            }

    },

    "repositories": [
            {
                    "type": "git",
                    "url": "https://github.com/tombenner/wp-mvc.git"
            }
    ],
    "require":{
            "tombenner/wp-mvc": "dev-master"
    }
```

without any issue, but given,
we have a  composer.json as:

```
   "config": {
            "allow-plugins": {
                    "composer/installers": true
            }

    },

    "repositories": [
            {
                    "type": "git",
                    "url": "https://github.com/sampoyigi/ti-ext-localepicker.git"
            }
    ],
    "require":{
            "sampoyigi/ti-ext-localepicker": "dev-master"
    }
```

when `composer install`

```
In RootPackageLoader.php line 160:

  require.ti-ext-localepicker is invalid, it should have a vendor name, a forward slash, and a package name. The vendor and packag
   name can be words separated by -, . or _. The complete name should match "^[a-z0-9]([_.-]?[a-z0-9]+)*/[a-z0-9](([_.]?|-{0,2})[a
  z0-9]+)*$".


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--dry-run] [--download-only] [--dev] [--no-suggest] [-dev] [--no-autoloader] [--no-progress] [--no-install] [--audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimiztoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--ignore-platform-rGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>...]
```

how can we add a "package" using composer where it is available on github.

Comment: is it available as composer dependency in github?

Comment: composer.json is missing on repo.

Comment: @AndréWalker, when a public repo without composer.json, can we still use it other way ? since it is the public repo and it is not mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error would manifest itself when you have

```json
"require":{
  "ti-ext-localepicker": "dev-master"
}
```

in your `composer.json`, not

```json
"require":{
  "sampoyigi/ti-ext-localepicker": "dev-master"
}
```

as you indicate in your original post. However, even with the second `require` in your `composer.json`, you should still get an error like:

```
[Composer\Repository\InvalidRepositoryException]                                                                                                  
No valid composer.json was found in any branch or tag of https://github.com/sampoyigi/ti-ext-localepicker.git, could not load a package from it.
```

Since the repository has no `composer.json` in its root, we would need to specify the metadata ourselves for Composer to be able to install it by using [`"type": "package"` with data in the `"package"` key](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2):

```json
{
  "config": {
    "allow-plugins": {
      "composer/installers": true
    }
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "sampoyigi/ti-ext-localepicker",
        "version": "dev-master",
        "dist": {
          "url": "https://github.com/sampoyigi/ti-ext-localepicker/archive/refs/heads/master.zip",
          "type": "zip"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "require":{
    "sampoyigi/ti-ext-localepicker": "dev-master"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Wongin,  any there any way to add this package without touching the composer.json file but still manager to use this package ? since touching the composer.json file then 'composer install' will delete some of the original packages where the app is not installed through composer in the first place.